# How come em and rem are different in my h1 tag?

Tags: css, fonts, responsive, typography

I've learned the basics of em and rem, but still can't figure out why em and rem for my h1 tag produce different font sizes here.

```
html {
  font-size: 100%;
}


body {
  background-color: white;

}

.page-heading {
  background-color: $primary-color;
}

h1 {
  font: 2rem 'Bungee Shade', cursive;
  color: white;
}
```

In this code I set the html font-size to 100% which is same as 16px. 
2rem therefore will always be 32px - when I replace the font-size with 32px i can confirm it is the same as 2rem.

However, when I change to 2em, the font-size is smaller, even though 1em should technically be 16px here. I played around with inserting different pixel font sizes and it seems like 2em equals to 28px here. For the life of me I can't figure out why!

Comment: [Here](https://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/) is a good article the describes all the lengths of css (including em and rem)

Comment: Not sure I understand. They're the same here https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWvYZg

Comment: You're right. But when i run my dev server and view on Chrome i don't get the same result. Weird?

Comment: Check the css rule chain in your dev tools for any conflicting rules in which the rule you didn't exist to win, won.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans how do i check the css rule in my dev tools?

Comment: @JosephLiu right click the thing on the page, "inspect element", it'll jump you straight to the DOM tree and the associated CSS styling.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans so i found out the default size of my body is 14px. Is there any reason why this is the case? I thought default size should always be 16px

Comment: no idea without additional information - see which file is responsible for setting it to 14px: rules are typically linked to which stylesheet effects those

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it's still a mystery to me. I only have 1 stylesheet which I've shown in my original post

Comment: is this on all browsers?